# The manifest disappeared from my android studio. I can't find the manifest

Tags: java, android

I was using "project structure" for Picasso, but the manifest disappeared.

I tried "Library Dependency" and Picasso creates it in my Android Studio.

This is my error:

```
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\arduino\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
ParseError at [row,col]:[22,5]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some error or missing tags in you manifest files that's why you are getting this error. Try to search your manifest file by double clicking `shift` button.

Comment: i mean i missing manifest files.. i find manifest by double clicking shift. but still an error..

Comment: What is the error when you click on the manifest after pressing double shift?

Comment: oh. when click double shift not another error. just i can find manifest file.but i think this is not mine. it is be nowhere to be found.